# Exoplayer not playing video in some devices

Tags: android-recyclerview, video-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am new to exoplayer.And I am trying to Play the list of videos in recyclerview.
But few videos are not playing and getting below error.

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Stop failed.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_stop(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.stop(MediaCodec.java:2084)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.releaseCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:608)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.releaseCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:508)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecRenderer.java:562)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:377)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.disable(BaseRenderer.java:153)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.disableRenderer(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:976)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.resetInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:764)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:735)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:355)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Can anybody please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

That error is typically thrown when the underlying platform does not support  something in the video like the codec or the profile level of the codec.

For example the video which does not play may use H.264 with High profile on a device which only support the Main or Baseline profiles (most devices).

You can check the details of your video using a tool like ffprobe:

- https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html

And you can see the up to date list of supported video formats here:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

Comment: ,Thank you I will check once